# Amount of positional parameters in Linux shell script

Tags: bash

I'm making a script (which is only a part of a way bigger script).

I want to make a script that:
moves the files that are in the directories mentioned in the parameters of my script to the directory /tmp

```
#!/bin/bash
mv "$1"/* /tmp
```

This once works fine when I only mention one directory in the parameter of my script.

If I'd want to be able to mention 3 directories in the parameters i could just copy paste and replace $1 by $2 and $3.

But isn't there a simpler way that would make it possible to to add an unlimited amount of parameters (directories) while executing my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through all the elements with `$@`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in "$@"
do
   mv "$dir"/* /tmp
done
```

So that you don't have to know in advance how many parameters you are getting.

Comment: `"$@"/*` would expand to (for 3 arguments) `"$1" "$2" "$3"/*`, not `"$1"/* "$2"/* "$3"/*`. That is, the `/*` is not bound to `$@` in any way, so it simply appears after the expansion of `"$@"`.

Comment: Thanks

I tried out with just changing the $1 to $@ out of curiosity, a strange thing happened:

my new script was:
#!/bin/bash
mv "$@"/* /tmp

I then executed the script with my 5 folders as parameters  
$ sh ss7.sh u1 u2 u3 u4 u5

The 4 first folders were moved to /tmp (which wasn't the purpose) and the 5th folder stayed and the files were moved to /tmp

So it did work for the 5th folder but not for the first 4, has anyone got an explanation for this?


pierrebernard@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sh ss7.sh u1 u2 u3 u4 u5

Comment: @user3742475 see what chepner explaned just above your comment. You need to loop through the elements in `$@`, because `$@/*` alone expands to `dir1 dir2 dir3/*`, so that efectively all dirs but last one are moved, while from last one just its content (`/*`) is moved. That's why my answer suggests to loop through the values. Try it!

Comment: As an aside, `zsh` has an option which *does* allow `"$@"/*` to expand in such a "distributive" fashion: `"${^@}"/*`.